# PyTorch lightning works on CUDA but throws "Training with multiple optimizers is only supported with manual optimization" error on MPS and CPU

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have some python code that uses PyTorch and the lightning module. It contains two neural network models that are optimised. It works well when the device is selected as CUDA. On a different machine, I have a Mac M1 chip and when I set the device to be MPS, I get the error

`File "/Users/Me/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/optimizer.py", line 185, in _init_optimizers_and_lr_schedulers _validate_multiple_optimizers_support(optimizers, model) File "/Users/Me/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/optimizer.py", line 341, in _validate_multiple_optimizers_support raise RuntimeError( RuntimeError: Training with multiple optimizers is only supported with manual optimization. Set "self.automatic_optimization = False", then access your optimizers in "training_step" with "opt1, opt2, ... = self.optimizers()".`

How come I get this error on MPS and not on CUDA? How can I resolve this? I get the same error when I use CPU.

I expected lightning to work on CPU and MPS too without changes in the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because PyTorch-Lightening 2.* does not support multiple optimizers in `automatic optimization` mode.

You can follow the following steps ([Ref](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/model/manual_optimization.html))

1. Set self.automatic_optimization = False in `__init__` method of `LightningModule` class.
2. In the `training_step` method, get access to the optimizers using `self.optimizers()`
3. Perform the manual optimzations using `opt.zero_grad()  -> self.manual_backward(loss) -> opt.step()` ([ref](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/model/manual_optimization.html))

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find you are using different Pytorch Lightning version on different systems?
It seems the automatic handling of multiple optimisers was removed in version 1.2: https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/pull/16539

In newer versions, as the error message states and the (AI?) answer by @mental_matrix outline, you need to use manual optimisation.